# Is there any way to resume live h264 playback (client rejoin) using the h.264 codec?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, h.264, media-source

Currently, I'm having a bit of an issue with the MediaSource API for resuming live h264 playback.
My server-side code will keep the first packet from FFmpeg, then dispatch it to clients. However, this works well but raises an issue.

When I restart the stream and it dispatches to the client(s), it goes as expected and this is the result I expect when a client disconnects then has to reconnect to the stream, is the aforementioned [result](https://go.is-rocket.science/6ffdf63d1f.png)

However, if I were to rejoin the stream, I get this as the [result](https://go.is-rocket.science/c5f6efb5a3.png)

Also, FFMpeg data is being sent to the client in the picture above, it's just not rendering it for some reason.

Here's my function for playing audio/video frames that I get from the server.

```js
private _playFrame(type: 0 | 1) {
    const src = type === 0 ? this.audioSource : this.videoSource;
    if (!src || src.updating) return;
    const queue = type === 0 ? this.audioFrameQueue : this.videoFrameQueue;
    src.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
    if (this.video.src && this.video.paused) this.video.play().then(() => null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragmented .mp4 data streams -- the type used for live playback -- have a prologue describing their media before the compressed media itself.

The prologue containing the media metadata is a chunk of data -- an "atom" in the lingo of mp4 -- named `'moov'`.  One of its subatoms, `'avcC'`, contains so-called codec-private data for H.264 video streams. If you ask a decoder to process H.264 without giving it the codec-private data, it cannot interpret the H.264 and so skips over it. This is true of any decoder, including the ones embedded in browser or desktop media player packages.

The `'moov'` prologue is probably in the first packet from ffmpeg (although you'd need to examine that data with a [tool like `mp4dump`](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dump/) to be sure).

So, to join a live stream a viewer must receive the prologue data and then the live data.

Comment: Well, I do give the MediaStream the first FFmpeg packet, but it still doesn't resume playback. Even when playing new data, that doesn't show, it's stuck infinitely loading.